# Prove for a $7\times7$ matrix that the set of all eigenvectors is linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is a $7\times7$ matrix, $\left\{\vec{v_{1}},\vec{v_{2}}\right\}$ is a basis for $\operatorname{Eig}(A,3)$, $\left\{\vec{v_{3}},\vec{v_{4}},\vec{v_{5}}\right\}$ is a basis for $\operatorname{Eig}(A,7)$ and $\left\{\vec{v_{6}},\vec{v_{7}}\right\}$ is a basis for $\operatorname{Eig}(A,-2)$. Prove that the set $\left\{\vec{v_{1}},\vec{v_{2}},\vec{v_{3}},\vec{v_{4}},\vec{v_{5}}\vec{v_{6}},\vec{v_{7}}\right\}$ is linearly independent.

What I think I am supposed to do is start with the dependence test equation:
$c_{1}\vec{v_{1}}+c_{2}\vec{v_{2}}+c_{3}\vec{v_{3}}+c_{4}\vec{v_{4}}+c_{5}\vec{v_{5}}+c_{6}\vec{v_{7}}+c_{7}\vec{v_{7}} =0$

Edit: I looked up online and found multiply both sides by $A-\lambda_{m}I$ to get $c_{1}(\lambda_{1}-\lambda_{m})\vec{v_{1}}+c_{2}(\lambda_{2}-\lambda_{m})\vec{v_{2}}+c_{3}(\lambda_{3}-\lambda_{m})\vec{v_{3}}+c_{4}(\lambda_{4}-\lambda_{m})\vec{v_{4}}+c_{5}(\lambda_{5}-\lambda_{m})\vec{v_{5}}+c_{6}(\lambda_{6}-\lambda_{m})\vec{v_{6}}+c_{7}(\lambda_{7}-\lambda_{m})\vec{v_{7}} =0$

I'm guessing in this case $\lambda_{m}$ would be $\lambda_{7}$

Comment: Sorry, what does $Eig(A,-2)$ means?

Comment: I think it's just an example, like for $\lambda$ = -2 that is the corresponding basis you would get. I don't think it matters in this problem, my teacher was just setting up the set of all eigenvectors for A.

Comment: @Ana: It is the eigenspace of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $-2$.

Comment: @AnaGalois Pienso que es el especio propio de valor propio $-2$.

Comment: @CameronBuie Thanks, I wasn't familiar with the notation.

Comment: @DevenWare ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Consider what happens when you multiply by $A-\lambda I_7,$ where $I_7$ is the $7\times 7$ identity matrix and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. What happens when you do this for all but one such $\lambda$?